# ¿Qué significa "siempre sí" y "siempre no"?

Tags: definiciones, méxico

Este fin de semana estaba en un hotel con una amiga esperando a otros amigos para salir juntos.  Mi amiga dijo a la recepcionista: -"Estamos esperando unos amigos. ¿Usted puede avisarnos cuando lleguen, por favor?"-

Pero nuestros amigos cancelaron, y después mi amiga dijo a la recepcionista: -"Siempre no vienen."-

¿Qué significa eso?

**Nota:** Esto pasó en México.

Comment: "Siempre nos fallan?"

Comment: "Siempre no" in Spanish is "Nunca" :)

Comment: @belisarius: Thus the question... the phrase didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Flimzy FWIW, it doesn't make sense to me neither (I'm Spanish).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me neither (from Argentina).

Comment: @leonbloy Makes perfect sense to me as a Mexican.

Comment: Jajaja, bienvenido a México amigo, a mí me pasó lo mismo la primera vez que oí semejante frase y cuando "siempre sí" me enteré de su significado me quedé en shock y aún hoy luego de años viviendo en México no puedo usarla porque soy incapaz de pronunciarla, no me sale, mi cerebro no logra conectarse con la lengua.

Answer (score 8):

Es un mejicanismo. De [aquí](http://www.fondodeculturaeconomica.com/obras/suma/r3/buscar.asp?idVocabulum=79&starts=S&word=siempre%20s%ED,%20siempre%20no):

> En 1896, Ramos y Duarte (Diccionario de mejicanismos) escribía que la expresión siempre no era propia del Distrito Federal y daba el siguiente ejemplo: "¿Va usted o no? —Siempre no voy". Y añadía: "suprímase el siempre, y estará bien; porque siempre significa 'en todo o en cualquier tiempo'". Algunos años antes, en 1892, José Sánchez Samoano, en su libro Modismos, locuciones y términos mexicanos, escribió al respecto el siguiente verso: "Allí [en México] es la palabra siempre / negación y afirmación; así dicen siempre sí / como dicen siempre no".
>           Efectivamente, en el español mexicano actual es frecuente que el adverbio siempre, acompañado de sí o no, equivalga semánticamente a 'al fin', 'de todos modos', 'definitivamente', 'resueltamente', 'en cualquier caso', según los diferentes contextos. Resultan así expresiones sumamente curiosas para quien sólo conoce los sentidos de siempre que registra la Academia. Vienen a ser así inanalizables expresiones tales como "siempre no se murió el viejito", "siempre sí fui a la fiesta", que cualquier mexicano dice y entiende.

Answer (score 6):

En inglés eso podría entenderse como "Actually, they are not coming".

- Siempre sí: Actually, yes.
- Siempre no: Actually, no.

Un ejemplo:

*Persona 1*: ¿Desea otra bebida?
*Persona 2*: Si por favor... pensándolo bien, siempre no.

En el contexto en el que tu amiga dijo eso, yo lo interpretaría como cambiar de opinión a último momento. De modo que otra forma en la que se podría decir lo mismo es: "Al final no vienen". De modo que la recepcionista entendería que ya no tiene que avisarles.

Answer (score 5):

Very simple: Whenever you see these phrases, think of the English phrase, "after all."

"Siempre no van a venir." = "[I thought they were coming, but] they're not coming after all."

"Siempre sí va a venir." = "[I thought she wasn't coming, but] she's coming after all."

It normally comes at the beginning of the sentences as opposed to "after all" which is appended to the end of a sentence, but the meaning is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Si realmente la amiga quería decir lo que dijo, la acción de "no venir" ocurre "siempre" y como dice belisarius, quería decir que "Nunca vienen". Por el contexto de la historia puede ser este su verdadero significado, pero es una construcción inusual.

Por eso, otra posibilidad sería que simplemente se equivocó, y quería decir "No siempre vienen", con el sentido de "Algunas veces no vienen".

Comment: Yo también pensé eso... pero no, resultó ser un mejicanismo que no significa exactamente eso. Está un poco difícil.

Answer (score 0):

En Bolivia se usa en la zona occidental (andina), con la variante que el *siempre* va al final.

> — ¿Vendrá fulano?
>   — No siempre.

Es reforzando la negativa. En este caso se usa si se insistió a fulano que viniese y decididamente no quiso venir.

Answer (score 0):

No están del todo bien captados los sentidos de las expresiones mexicanas "siempre sí" y "siempre no".

- ¿Vienes a la cena?
- Siempre sí.
  En ese diálogo se sobreentiende que quien pregunta, ya había oído decir al interrogado que no iría. Pero vuelve a preguntar como un modo de insistir en que vaya a la cena. El interrogado dice siempre sí, para reconocer que había dicho que no, pero que ha cambiado de opinión.
  José Blanco (mexicano)